# Is Ezekiel 28 referring to the King of Tyre or Satan?

Tags: ezekiel--the-book

Because in no sense would god call a mortal human an Anointed cherub

**You were in Eden, the garden of God;  Every precious stone was your adornment:  Carnelian, chrysolite, and amethyst;  Beryl, lapis lazuli, and jasper;  Sapphire, turquoise, and emerald;  And gold beautifully wrought for you,  Mined for you, prepared the day you were created. 
I created you as a cherub  With outstretched shielding wings;  And you resided on God’s holy mountain;  You walked among stones of fire.**
(Ezekiel 28:13-14)

I don't know. I've come here to ask other people who must have read this verse in hebrew as I don't know it.
Perhaps they'd know what it's actually about.

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) and thanks for this first question. Great to have you learn with us!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, that seems like a pretty good translation of the original Hebrew to me.

The Talmud (Bava Basra 75a) expounds these verses as referring to neither Hiram nor Satan but rather Adam. Hence, “You were in Eden, the garden of G-d.” The remainder of the passage is indicative of the honor bestowed upon him while he was still in the Garden.

> אמר רבי חמא (בר) חנינא עשר חופות עשה הקדוש ברוך הוא לאדם הראשון בגן עדן שנאמר (יחזקאל כח, יג) בעדן גן אלהים היית כל אבן יקרה וגו' מר זוטרא אמר אחת עשרה שנאמר כל אבן יקרה אמר רבי יוחנן וגרוע שבכולן זהב דקא חשיב ליה לבסוף
>   R’ Chama (son of) Chanuna said, G-d made ten canopies for Adam in the Garden of Eden [...]

Now, the simple meaning of the passage is that Ezekiel is speaking to Hiram king of Tyre, so what’s the connection to Adam? The Talmud (ibid.-75b) explains:

> מאי (יחזקאל כח, יג) מלאכת תופיך ונקביך בך אמר רב יהודה אמר רב אמר לו הקדוש ברוך הוא לחירם מלך צור בך נסתכלתי ובראתי נקבים נקבים באדם ואיכא דאמרי הכי קאמר בך נסתכלתי וקנסתי מיתה על אדם הראשון
>
> What is “The worksmanship of your drums and of your holes”? Rav Yehudah said that Rav said, G-d said to Hiram king of Tyre: In you did I peer [I saw that you would declare yourself a god] and I made many holes [referring to the digestive tract] in man. Others explain that this is what He was saying: In you did I peer and I decreed death on Adam.

In summary: the passage refers to Adam, whose creation was impacted by his descendant Hiram’s declaration that he was a god.